# Submit iOS app for specific devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to build an app and tried to make it only support *iPhone6, iPhone6 Plus* but when submitted the app to **App Store**. They rejected it because it was crashing on iPad. How can I remove the iPad support and the other devices as well. In **Xcode** in **Deployment Info**, [Devices] is set to [iPhone].

**EDIT:**

My app uses M8 chip that's why I want to limit it to *iPhone6, iPhone6 Plus* only. As for the iPad I can't offer support it now because I can't maintain testing it and keep updating its design every time I update my app.

**EDIT2:**

In **Xcode** in **Deployment Info**, [Deployment Target] is set to [8.1].

Comment: Apps have to support all iPhone sizes and run as-is on the iPad.

Comment: @maddy They do not. You can limit the target devices if needed, especially iPhone/iPad

Comment: Is your app universal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Targeted device family. Select the project, then info-->Deployment--->Targeted device family to iPhone only and you have to do the same thing in targets. After that your app will be only for iPhone.

Good Luck!

Comment: if you mean Build Settings-->Targeted Device Family, it is set to iPhone. because there is no deployment in Info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way yet to set app only for iPhone 6/6+, however you can prevent running it on iPad by setting the correct title. You can't prevent running your own app on iPhone 5 till you have allowed it to run on iPhone 6/6+. iPhone, iPad or both, no versions.

Comment: Select project, head to Info, then Deployment, Targeted device family and set it to iPhone. @iEmad

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can choose which kinds of devices you are supporting for. But, you can choose minimum iOS version that your app supports in the **Deployment Target**. I think your solution will be changing the **Deployment Target** to iOS 8.0 and you are good to go.

For your problem of rejection, you can change your supported iDevice to support iPhone only from your app target in **XCode**. Then on the **General** tab, you can change it from the **Deployment Target** portion.

Comment: **my deployment target of device is iPhone already**. I forgot to mention, but my deployment Target is 8.1

Comment: You are good to go as long as you choose iPhone only. I think you did not set it properly when the time you submitted it? And you don't really have the options to choose what kinds of **iDevice** you can choose explicitly.

Comment: I am sure that that's the way to change your deployment iDevice whether you are supporting iPad or iPhone. So, clean up your build and make sure that your minimum iOS version. And you are good to go.